# Some Issues with ListPlot3D

Tags: plotting

A have a large list of {x,y,z} coordinates in the box [0,1]x[0,1]x[0,1] and I am interested in plotting surfaces from them. Unfortunately, sometimes the surface is disconnected, or it is multi-valued in z (for instance, 4 quarter cylinders at the corners of the box), and ListPlot3D seems to try to interpolate this as if it is one connected surface, or isn't able to handle the multi-valued z's properly. My temporary work-around has been to use ListPointPlot3D, but is there a way to generate the surfaces properly?

I had to reduce the amount of points because the data set was too large, but here's an idea of what I'm talking about:

```
data = {{0.0, 0.23999999999999999, 0.0}, {0.0, 0.23999999999999999, 0.083333333333333329}, {0.0, 0.23999999999999999, 0.16666666666666666}, {0.0, 0.23999999999999999, 0.25}, {0.0, 0.23999999999999999, 0.33333333333333331}, {0.0, 0.23999999999999999, 0.41666666666666669}, {0.0, 0.23999999999999999, 0.5}, {0.0, 0.23999999999999999, 0.58333333333333337}, {0.0, 0.23999999999999999, 0.66666666666666663}, {0.0, 0.23999999999999999, 0.75}, {0.0, 0.23999999999999999, 0.83333333333333337}, {0.0, 0.23999999999999999, 0.91666666666666663}, {0.0, 0.76000000000000001, 0.0}, {0.0, 0.76000000000000001, 0.083333333333333329}, {0.0, 0.76000000000000001, 0.16666666666666666}, {0.0, 0.76000000000000001, 0.25}, {0.0, 0.76000000000000001, 0.33333333333333331}, {0.0, 0.76000000000000001, 0.41666666666666669}, {0.0, 0.76000000000000001, 0.5}, {0.0, 0.76000000000000001, 0.58333333333333337}, {0.0, 0.76000000000000001, 0.66666666666666663}, {0.0, 0.76000000000000001, 0.75}, {0.0, 0.76000000000000001, 0.83333333333333337}, {0.0, 0.76000000000000001, 0.91666666666666663}, {0.040000000000000001, 0.23999999999999999, 0.0}, {0.040000000000000001, 0.23999999999999999, 0.083333333333333329}, {0.040000000000000001, 0.23999999999999999, 0.16666666666666666}, {0.040000000000000001, 0.23999999999999999, 0.25}, {0.040000000000000001, 0.23999999999999999, 0.33333333333333331}, {0.040000000000000001, 0.23999999999999999, 0.41666666666666669}, {0.040000000000000001, 0.23999999999999999, 0.5}, {0.040000000000000001, 0.23999999999999999, 0.58333333333333337}, {0.040000000000000001, 0.23999999999999999, 0.66666666666666663}, {0.040000000000000001, 0.23999999999999999, 0.75}, {0.040000000000000001, 0.23999999999999999, 0.83333333333333337}, {0.040000000000000001, 0.23999999999999999, 0.91666666666666663}, {0.040000000000000001, 0.76000000000000001, 0.0}, {0.040000000000000001, 0.76000000000000001, 0.083333333333333329}, {0.040000000000000001, 0.76000000000000001, 0.16666666666666666}, {0.040000000000000001, 0.76000000000000001, 0.25}, {0.040000000000000001, 0.76000000000000001, 0.33333333333333331}, {0.040000000000000001, 0.76000000000000001, 0.41666666666666669}, {0.040000000000000001, 0.76000000000000001, 0.5}, {0.040000000000000001, 0.76000000000000001, 0.58333333333333337}, {0.040000000000000001, 0.76000000000000001, 0.66666666666666663}, {0.040000000000000001, 0.76000000000000001, 0.75}, {0.040000000000000001, 0.76000000000000001, 0.83333333333333337}, {0.040000000000000001, 0.76000000000000001, 0.91666666666666663}, {0.16, 0.20000000000000001, 0.0}, {0.16, 0.20000000000000001, 0.083333333333333329}, {0.16, 0.20000000000000001, 0.16666666666666666}, {0.16, 0.20000000000000001, 0.25}, {0.16, 0.20000000000000001, 0.33333333333333331}, {0.16, 0.20000000000000001, 0.41666666666666669}, {0.16, 0.20000000000000001, 0.5}, {0.16, 0.20000000000000001, 0.58333333333333337}, {0.16, 0.20000000000000001, 0.66666666666666663}, {0.16, 0.20000000000000001, 0.75}, {0.16, 0.20000000000000001, 0.83333333333333337}, {0.16, 0.20000000000000001, 0.91666666666666663}, {0.16, 0.80000000000000004, 0.0}, {0.16, 0.80000000000000004, 0.083333333333333329}, {0.16, 0.80000000000000004, 0.16666666666666666}, {0.16, 0.80000000000000004, 0.25}, {0.16, 0.80000000000000004, 0.33333333333333331}, {0.16, 0.80000000000000004, 0.41666666666666669}, {0.16, 0.80000000000000004, 0.5}, {0.16, 0.80000000000000004, 0.58333333333333337}, {0.16, 0.80000000000000004, 0.66666666666666663}, {0.16, 0.80000000000000004, 0.75}, {0.16, 0.80000000000000004, 0.83333333333333337}, {0.16, 0.80000000000000004, 0.91666666666666663}, {0.20000000000000001, 0.16, 0.0}, {0.20000000000000001, 0.16, 0.083333333333333329}, {0.20000000000000001, 0.16, 0.16666666666666666}, {0.20000000000000001, 0.16, 0.25}, {0.20000000000000001, 0.16, 0.33333333333333331}, {0.20000000000000001, 0.16, 0.41666666666666669}, {0.20000000000000001, 0.16, 0.5}, {0.20000000000000001, 0.16, 0.58333333333333337}, {0.20000000000000001, 0.16, 0.66666666666666663}, {0.20000000000000001, 0.16, 0.75}, {0.20000000000000001, 0.16, 0.83333333333333337}, {0.20000000000000001, 0.16, 0.91666666666666663}, {0.20000000000000001, 0.83999999999999997, 0.0}, {0.20000000000000001, 0.83999999999999997, 0.083333333333333329}, {0.20000000000000001, 0.83999999999999997, 0.16666666666666666}, {0.20000000000000001, 0.83999999999999997, 0.25}, {0.20000000000000001, 0.83999999999999997, 0.33333333333333331}, {0.20000000000000001, 0.83999999999999997, 0.41666666666666669}, {0.20000000000000001, 0.83999999999999997, 0.5}, {0.20000000000000001, 0.83999999999999997, 0.58333333333333337}, {0.20000000000000001, 0.83999999999999997, 0.66666666666666663}, {0.20000000000000001, 0.83999999999999997, 0.75}, {0.20000000000000001, 0.83999999999999997, 0.83333333333333337}, {0.20000000000000001, 0.83999999999999997, 0.91666666666666663}, {0.23999999999999999, 0.0, 0.0}, {0.23999999999999999, 0.0, 0.083333333333333329}, {0.23999999999999999, 0.0, 0.16666666666666666}, {0.23999999999999999, 0.0, 0.25}, {0.23999999999999999, 0.0, 0.33333333333333331}, {0.23999999999999999, 0.0, 0.41666666666666669}, {0.23999999999999999, 0.0, 0.5}, {0.23999999999999999, 0.0, 0.58333333333333337}, {0.23999999999999999, 0.0, 0.66666666666666663}, {0.23999999999999999, 0.0, 0.75}, {0.23999999999999999, 0.0, 0.83333333333333337}, {0.23999999999999999, 0.0, 0.91666666666666663}, {0.23999999999999999, 0.040000000000000001, 0.0}, {0.23999999999999999, 0.040000000000000001, 0.083333333333333329}, {0.23999999999999999, 0.040000000000000001, 0.16666666666666666}, {0.23999999999999999, 0.040000000000000001, 0.25}, {0.23999999999999999, 0.040000000000000001, 0.33333333333333331}, {0.23999999999999999, 0.040000000000000001, 0.41666666666666669}, {0.23999999999999999, 0.040000000000000001, 0.5}, {0.23999999999999999, 0.040000000000000001, 0.58333333333333337}, {0.23999999999999999, 0.040000000000000001, 0.66666666666666663}, {0.23999999999999999, 0.040000000000000001, 0.75}, {0.23999999999999999, 0.040000000000000001, 0.83333333333333337}, {0.23999999999999999, 0.040000000000000001, 0.91666666666666663}, {0.23999999999999999, 0.95999999999999996, 0.0}, {0.23999999999999999, 0.95999999999999996, 0.083333333333333329}, {0.23999999999999999, 0.95999999999999996, 0.16666666666666666}, {0.23999999999999999, 0.95999999999999996, 0.25}, {0.23999999999999999, 0.95999999999999996, 0.33333333333333331}, {0.23999999999999999, 0.95999999999999996, 0.41666666666666669}, {0.23999999999999999, 0.95999999999999996, 0.5}, {0.23999999999999999, 0.95999999999999996, 0.58333333333333337}, {0.23999999999999999, 0.95999999999999996, 0.66666666666666663}, {0.23999999999999999, 0.95999999999999996, 0.75}, {0.23999999999999999, 0.95999999999999996, 0.83333333333333337}, {0.23999999999999999, 0.95999999999999996, 0.91666666666666663}, {0.76000000000000001, 0.0, 0.0}, {0.76000000000000001, 0.0, 0.083333333333333329}, {0.76000000000000001, 0.0, 0.16666666666666666}, {0.76000000000000001, 0.0, 0.25}, {0.76000000000000001, 0.0, 0.33333333333333331}, {0.76000000000000001, 0.0, 0.41666666666666669}, {0.76000000000000001, 0.0, 0.5}, {0.76000000000000001, 0.0, 0.58333333333333337}, {0.76000000000000001, 0.0, 0.66666666666666663}, {0.76000000000000001, 0.0, 0.75}, {0.76000000000000001, 0.0, 0.83333333333333337}, {0.76000000000000001, 0.0, 0.91666666666666663}, {0.76000000000000001, 0.040000000000000001, 0.0}, {0.76000000000000001, 0.040000000000000001, 0.083333333333333329}, {0.76000000000000001, 0.040000000000000001, 0.16666666666666666}, {0.76000000000000001, 0.040000000000000001, 0.25}, {0.76000000000000001, 0.040000000000000001, 0.33333333333333331}, {0.76000000000000001, 0.040000000000000001, 0.41666666666666669}, {0.76000000000000001, 0.040000000000000001, 0.5}, {0.76000000000000001, 0.040000000000000001, 0.58333333333333337}, {0.76000000000000001, 0.040000000000000001, 0.66666666666666663}, {0.76000000000000001, 0.040000000000000001, 0.75}, {0.76000000000000001, 0.040000000000000001, 0.83333333333333337}, {0.76000000000000001, 0.040000000000000001, 0.91666666666666663}, {0.76000000000000001, 0.95999999999999996, 0.0}, {0.76000000000000001, 0.95999999999999996, 0.083333333333333329}, {0.76000000000000001, 0.95999999999999996, 0.16666666666666666}, {0.76000000000000001, 0.95999999999999996, 0.25}, {0.76000000000000001, 0.95999999999999996, 0.33333333333333331}, {0.76000000000000001, 0.95999999999999996, 0.41666666666666669}, {0.76000000000000001, 0.95999999999999996, 0.5}, {0.76000000000000001, 0.95999999999999996, 0.58333333333333337}, {0.76000000000000001, 0.95999999999999996, 0.66666666666666663}, {0.76000000000000001, 0.95999999999999996, 0.75}, {0.76000000000000001, 0.95999999999999996, 0.83333333333333337}, {0.76000000000000001, 0.95999999999999996, 0.91666666666666663}, {0.80000000000000004, 0.16, 0.0}, {0.80000000000000004, 0.16, 0.083333333333333329}, {0.80000000000000004, 0.16, 0.16666666666666666}, {0.80000000000000004, 0.16, 0.25}, {0.80000000000000004, 0.16, 0.33333333333333331}, {0.80000000000000004, 0.16, 0.41666666666666669}, {0.80000000000000004, 0.16, 0.5}, {0.80000000000000004, 0.16, 0.58333333333333337}, {0.80000000000000004, 0.16, 0.66666666666666663}, {0.80000000000000004, 0.16, 0.75}, {0.80000000000000004, 0.16, 0.83333333333333337}, {0.80000000000000004, 0.16, 0.91666666666666663}, {0.80000000000000004, 0.83999999999999997, 0.0}, {0.80000000000000004, 0.83999999999999997, 0.083333333333333329}, {0.80000000000000004, 0.83999999999999997, 0.16666666666666666}, {0.80000000000000004, 0.83999999999999997, 0.25}, {0.80000000000000004, 0.83999999999999997, 0.33333333333333331}, {0.80000000000000004, 0.83999999999999997, 0.41666666666666669}, {0.80000000000000004, 0.83999999999999997, 0.5}, {0.80000000000000004, 0.83999999999999997, 0.58333333333333337}, {0.80000000000000004, 0.83999999999999997, 0.66666666666666663}, {0.80000000000000004, 0.83999999999999997, 0.75}, {0.80000000000000004, 0.83999999999999997, 0.83333333333333337}, {0.80000000000000004, 0.83999999999999997, 0.91666666666666663}, {0.83999999999999997, 0.20000000000000001, 0.0}, {0.83999999999999997, 0.20000000000000001, 0.083333333333333329}, {0.83999999999999997, 0.20000000000000001, 0.16666666666666666}, {0.83999999999999997, 0.20000000000000001, 0.25}, {0.83999999999999997, 0.20000000000000001, 0.33333333333333331}, {0.83999999999999997, 0.20000000000000001, 0.41666666666666669}, {0.83999999999999997, 0.20000000000000001, 0.5}, {0.83999999999999997, 0.20000000000000001, 0.58333333333333337}, {0.83999999999999997, 0.20000000000000001, 0.66666666666666663}, {0.83999999999999997, 0.20000000000000001, 0.75}, {0.83999999999999997, 0.20000000000000001, 0.83333333333333337}, {0.83999999999999997, 0.20000000000000001, 0.91666666666666663}, {0.83999999999999997, 0.80000000000000004, 0.0}, {0.83999999999999997, 0.80000000000000004, 0.083333333333333329}, {0.83999999999999997, 0.80000000000000004, 0.16666666666666666}, {0.83999999999999997, 0.80000000000000004, 0.25}, {0.83999999999999997, 0.80000000000000004, 0.33333333333333331}, {0.83999999999999997, 0.80000000000000004, 0.41666666666666669}, {0.83999999999999997, 0.80000000000000004, 0.5}, {0.83999999999999997, 0.80000000000000004, 0.58333333333333337}, {0.83999999999999997, 0.80000000000000004, 0.66666666666666663}, {0.83999999999999997, 0.80000000000000004, 0.75}, {0.83999999999999997, 0.80000000000000004, 0.83333333333333337}, {0.83999999999999997, 0.80000000000000004, 0.91666666666666663}, {0.95999999999999996, 0.23999999999999999, 0.0}, {0.95999999999999996, 0.23999999999999999, 0.083333333333333329}, {0.95999999999999996, 0.23999999999999999, 0.16666666666666666}, {0.95999999999999996, 0.23999999999999999, 0.25}, {0.95999999999999996, 0.23999999999999999, 0.33333333333333331}, {0.95999999999999996, 0.23999999999999999, 0.41666666666666669}, {0.95999999999999996, 0.23999999999999999, 0.5}, {0.95999999999999996, 0.23999999999999999, 0.58333333333333337}, {0.95999999999999996, 0.23999999999999999, 0.66666666666666663}, {0.95999999999999996, 0.23999999999999999, 0.75}, {0.95999999999999996, 0.23999999999999999, 0.83333333333333337}, {0.95999999999999996, 0.23999999999999999, 0.91666666666666663}, {0.95999999999999996, 0.76000000000000001, 0.0}, {0.95999999999999996, 0.76000000000000001, 0.083333333333333329}, {0.95999999999999996, 0.76000000000000001, 0.16666666666666666}, {0.95999999999999996, 0.76000000000000001, 0.25}, {0.95999999999999996, 0.76000000000000001, 0.33333333333333331}, {0.95999999999999996, 0.76000000000000001, 0.41666666666666669}, {0.95999999999999996, 0.76000000000000001, 0.5}, {0.95999999999999996, 0.76000000000000001, 0.58333333333333337}, {0.95999999999999996, 0.76000000000000001, 0.66666666666666663}, {0.95999999999999996, 0.76000000000000001, 0.75}, {0.95999999999999996, 0.76000000000000001, 0.83333333333333337}, {0.95999999999999996, 0.76000000000000001, 0.91666666666666663}}
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Problems with code/data often require the code/data for a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rdata = Reverse[data, 2];
f = FindClusters[rdata, 4];
ListPlot3D[Table[f[[i]], {i, 1, 4}], AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]